# Using a unique pointer to call a function crashes my program

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, inheritance, smart-pointers

I made a really simple program to try fusing unique pointers and inheritance together. But, it ends up crashing with exit code 11 and I don't know why. Can Anyone explain the reason for the crash?

```
//Counter Class, Base class
class Counter {
   public:
    virtual int addStuff(int& x)=0;
  };
```

```
//Derived Class, child class of Counter
class Stuff:public Counter {
 public:
  virtual int addStuff(int& x) override;
};
```

```
//Main function using unique pointers to call addStuff from Stuff class
int main() {
  int x = 12;
  std::unique_ptr<Stuff> p;
  p->addStuff(x);
}
```

Comment: Calling a member function on an uninitialized pointer can easily cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer `p` is [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) and points to nothing.

> Constructs a `std::unique_ptr` that owns nothing. Value-initializes the stored pointer and the stored deleter.

[Dereference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) on it leads to UB, anything is possible.

> The behavior is undefined if `get() == nullptr`

You should make `p` pointing to a valid object, e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<Stuff> p = std::make_unique<Stuff>();
```